# Read excel till specific rows in pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Suppose I have these rows in a column in my excel. There are other columns as well with values.

```
Gross Rent
Unit 1
Unit 2
Unit 3
Unit 4
Unit 5
Gross Rental Income
Other Income
Management Fees
Total Income
Expenses incurred for rent generation
Other Expenses
Operating profit
```

Here Units are house addresses. These can be of any count. So my boundary data is Gross Rental Income. I want to parse this header in 2 parts. one part is before *Gross Rental Income* and other after *Gross Rental Income*. How can I achieve the same using pandas. One approach I used to get index of *Gross Rental Income* and read the data in range before and after it.

```
excel_obj = pd.ExcelFile('excel_file')
df_property = excel_obj.parse('Sheet 1')
start_index = 0
end_index = df_property.index[df_property['Gross Rent'] == "Gross Rental Income"].tolist()[0]
df_property_units = df_property.iloc[0:end_index]
df_property_finacials = df_property.iloc[end_index:]
```

Is there any simpler approach.

Answer (score 0):

As column names are in string format and you can not slice it. The basic method you can use is to pass column name whichever you want and store in variable for reference. 
Below is just a sample;

```
   df1 = df[['column1','column2'[, ...]]
   df2 = df[['column5','column6'[, ...]]
```

Hope this will work for you.